# selectOneMenu doesn't update with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to update a selectOneMenu based on the change made from another selectOneMenu by using ajax.

my **xhtml**:

```
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo:" for="tipoCombo" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoCombo" value="#{equipamentoBean.tipo}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{equipamentoBean.tipos}"></f:selectItems>
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{equipamentoBean.listaSoftwares}" update="mainForm:softwareCombo" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Software:" for="softwareCombo" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="softwareCombo" value="#{equipamentoBean.software}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{equipamentoBean.softwares}"></f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

When i change my tipoCombo the ajax should call the method listaSoftwares on my equipamentoBean and then my softwareCombo would be populated

**listaSoftware**

```
    public void listaSoftwares(){
        System.out.println("Carregando softwares");
        this.softwares = new EquipamentoSoftwareDao().listaSoftwarePorTipo(1);
        System.out.println("Carregado");
    }
```

I added the System.out.println("Carregando softwares"); to see if the method was being called, but nothing happens

I'm following the prime showCase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

I tried different ways, but this one seems to be the right one.

**@Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EquipamentoBean {

    private List<Equipamento> equipamentos;
    private Equipamento equipamento;
    private List<Equipamento> equipamentosFiltrados;    
    private List<EquipamentoTipo> tipos;    
    private EquipamentoTipo tipo;
    private List<Regiao> regioes;
    private Regiao regiao;
    private List<EquipamentoSoftware> softwares;
    private EquipamentoSoftware software;

    public EquipamentoBean(){

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("init");
        tipo = new EquipamentoTipo();
        //Pega os equipamentos no banco
        this.equipamentos = new EquipamentoDao().listaEquipamentos();
        this.tipos = new EquipamentoTipoDao().listaTipos();
        this.regioes = new RegiaoDao().listaRegioes();

        System.out.println("init end");
    }

    public void salva(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        EquipamentoDao dao = new EquipamentoDao();
        dao.salva(equipamento);
        addMessage("Equipamento Salvo!");
    }

    public void addMessage(String summary){
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, summary, null);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }

    public void listaSoftwares(ChangeEvent eg){
        System.out.println("Carregando softwares");
        this.softwares = new EquipamentoSoftwareDao().listaSoftwarePorTipo(1);
        System.out.println("Carregado");
    }
    public List<EquipamentoTipo> listarTipos(){
        this.tipos = new EquipamentoTipoDao().listaTipos();
        return tipos;
    }

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed to:

```
            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo:" for="tipoCombo" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoCombo" value="#{equipamentoBean.tipo.nome}" >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{equipamentoBean.tipos}" var="#{tipo}" itemValue="#{tipo.nome}"></f:selectItems>
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{equipamentoBean.listaSoftwares}" update="mainForm:softwareCombo" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now its working

ref: http://www.guj.com.br/29357-primefaces-erro-ao-atualizar-um-selectonemenu-usando-ajax